# How to make my Angular 5 app works as expected by using best convention rules?

Tags: angular, nested, components

I'm learning angular, and I would like to build an app that has an Dashboard as shown there,

[image]

There would be some categories on the left, like products, employees, customers etc, where I would like to add edit or delete
data related to products, emplyees, customers etc, so when any of categories is clicked as I draw there should open for example
list of products, and by selecting any of them I would like to edit, or delete any of them, and also to add new

So I'm wondering how can I achieve this stuffs about adding, deleting, removing products for example, 
Should I create there a nested component that would have add, delete, edit buttons, and another big component which should
hold list of products and that 3 buttons?

Or how this should be done?

**And is it possible to use this 3 buttons for all of my categories, bcz they will all have add, edit, delete, but I don't know how to use it for all of them cuz all of them are adding different things to database?**

Can anyone give me please some tips about this task, thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 3):

The general idea is to create individual components for the self-contained units of your applications, in your case you will most likely have a `sidenav` component, which will hold your different categories, an `activeCategory` component, which will display the information related to the currently selected category (i.e. Products) and an `options` component, which will have the add, delete, etc. functionalities.

My suggestion is to go through the Angular 5 official [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial), which covers all the main aspect of building a modern Angular app from scratch. You can then reuse and adapt those concepts to implement your idea.

Answer (score 2):

To Answer this,

**And is it possible to use this 3 buttons for all of my categories, bcz they will all have add, edit, delete, but I don't know how to use it for all of them cuz all of them are adding different things to database?**

Yes. You can create generic service/component to use same buttons to process command for all items. You can use EventEmitter to achieve this.

I will suggest you start coding looking at tutorial, you will get some ideas, if not then people can help you with the problems you will face.

Happy Coding!